# Visual Studio, Defined Function Not Recognized?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using visual studio professional 2013. I have attached my header file with function prototypes to my main file. The compiler is saying that "'assignNum': identifier not found." I have absolutely no clue what's wrong, but I figured somebody else might. Here's the relevant code:

**Main File**

```
#include "Bullets.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>`enter code here`
#include <cstdlib>


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    greetings();
    assignNum();
    return 0;
}
```

**Header File**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
void greetings();
void assignNum();
```

Comment: Grr, "stdafx".  Got to love compiler lock-in.

Comment: greetings() works? I suspect a typo - assingNum for example

Comment: please post the message

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Huh? What does "stdafx.h" have to do with compiler lock-in?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's generated by default and includes Windows-specific headers.  So people think they're writing a "C" program and are actually writing a winapi one.

Comment: @James stdafx.h is 100% optional. You can create an empty project and write portable C. It'll compile just fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: That's a pretty loose definition of a lock you've got. By the time someone gets around to the point where they are compiling their code on multiple compilers, I would hope they would have enough experience to figure out how to delete a couple of lines in a header file.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the precompiled header feature...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Must be the **first** line in your cpp file. Remove it from your h file.